How we can login customers in a Iframe in magento 2.4.5
I am trying to login the customers in a iframe in magento2.4.5 but when i am trying to login after giving the proper credentials is not going the customer account index page. and in network call it is throwing 300 error status. Also, my x-frame-options is set to crossorigin. And in logs also there is no error found related to it.
Please provide me the possible scenarios it is affecting which is not letting me to login,and how we can achieve this.
It would be great if you can help me on this. Thanks.
Re-Phrased --
So, want I am doing is I have a headless magento project , on there all the actions performed in the site will be done on headless environment but when the customer is clicking on "proceed to checkout" button it should load the checkout page in a Iframe and the rest checkout flow will be done on the Iframe.
For this we are sending(from headless frontend) a Iframe url with customer access token and customer email id to re-login in magento2.4.5. for maintaining the sessions.If the login customer token is not expired then we will check and redirect it to checkout page otherwise not.
So my main expectation is how to load a magento checkout page in a Iframe in magneto 2.4.5 and how we can achieve this.

First guess, I'd say you probably have a problem with the browser blocking 3rd-party cookies - assuming, the iframe embed happens on a different origin? But it is hard to say, with a problem description so vague.

@C3roe, let me repharse my question what i actually want to achieve.

@C3roe, I have rephrased my question, please have a look and let me know , it would be great if you can help me.

From my point of view the rephrasing just adds more text to the question without actually addressing the main issue raised by C3roe: A difference in origin. You can read "origin" as "domain". See also: Third-party cookies. Browsers tend to often block these cookies.
